# sqlbulkcopy exception in production only

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am having a very strange behavior. When I test the application locally, everything works fine, with IIS Express, latest release of VisualStudio 2015 Update 3.

But the live application running on IIS8 on Windows Server 2012, sometimes it doesn't.

**Sometimes** I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: String or binary data would be truncated.
```

I log the data processed by the application, if take the exact same data file generating the exception in production, and I run it on my local machine (connected to production DB), it works great. No exception.

The real reason for the exception cannot be the length of the DB column, because I checked the data, field by field. And by the way if it was a problem of string length, I would get the exception locally too.

This is the datatable definition:

```
  var dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("gid", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("season", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("brand", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("brandid", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("pattern", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("width", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("ratio", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("diameter", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("load", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("speed", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("isrunflat", typeof(bool));
  dt.Columns.Add("price", typeof(decimal));
  dt.Columns.Add("original_descr", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("source", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("createdon", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Columns.Add("updatedon", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Columns.Add("eulgas", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("eulrai", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("eulnc", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("euldb", typeof(string));
```

And this is the database table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[grabbed_zero](
    [gid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [season] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [brand] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [brandid] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [pattern] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [width] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ratio] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [diameter] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [load] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [speed] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [isrunflat] [int] NOT NULL,
    [price] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [original_descr] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [source] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [createdon] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [updatedon] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EULGAS] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EULRAI] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EULNC] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EULDB] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
)
```

I am banging my head against every wall I can find, but still no ideas comes out about what may be the cause for this.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Probably one of the strings you're adding to your string columns in your `DataTable` overflows the length constraints defined by the table for that column?

Comment: @KirkWoll I checked the length of the strings in debug one by one, and they are within limit, plus if I use the same data file in production and locally on my development machine, it works locally, it generate the exception in production. Using the same DB, the same code, and the same data. Must be something on the server, but I am guessing what.

Comment: "I launch the application in release mode locally I have the exception", so remove column by column in release mode until you find out exactly which column throws the error. That will be easier to target one or many specific columns than unknown columns to find the bug. One thing you can do afterward is performing a for each with an insert. You will know exactly which values cause the issue. That will help you/or us to debug this weird issue.

Answer (score 2):

What I found out at the end is the problem was originated by json deserialization, which was behaving differently in release mode than debug mode.

The data files being bulk copied were originally in json format.

When I found out, I just made a nuget Update-Package -reinstall for newtonsoft package (which was already updated to latest release) and it solved the issue.

Was unrelated to sqlbulkcopy.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding string dataColumn using the following code:

```
DataColumn d = new DataColumn(fieldname, typeof(string));
d.MaxLength = 10; //Specify max length
dt.Columns.Add(d);
```

So the exception will be thrown when inserting data into dataTable and you will specify the column

Comment: Changed my code to use your code for column definition, but it still throwing the exception. What I found out in the mean while is if I launch the application in release mode locally I have the exception, in debug mode no. Same thing in production, tried publishing in debug mode and it works. But I don't understand why.